# VBA BUTTON to copy from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, buttonclick, commandbutton, vba

and need help to accomplish a specific copy and paste. I have an active customer list That is always updating. And when the work is complete I have to prepare an invoice. I am trying with no success to create a button on my active costumer workbook that will copy the customer name that I select maybe by highlighting the cell which Is in column c, then transfer that name to a template named invoice in cell B3. The template already set up with Vlookup and if function to populate all information based on the customer name. I want the button to copy the cell that I select not a whole column or row. Is this code possible?

Answer (score 1):

Both these suggestions assume that you are in the Customer workbook/sheet with the cell selected ... button code could look like this:

```
Sub Copy_Cust()
    Workbooks("Invoice").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = ActiveCell
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub Copy_Cust2()
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("Invoice").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mike I'll try that and let you know

Comment: Hi I tried the second option and It accomplished the first part which is coping the selected cell. how would I combine it to now transfer the customer to the service work book. :Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim CustomerName As String
Dim serviceInvoice As Workbook
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Active").Select
Customer = Range("C1") = ActiveCell
Set serviceInvoice = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Service Dept\Templates\Service Invoice.xls")
Worksheets("Invoice1").Select
Worksheets("Invoice1").Range("B3").Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With
serviceInvoice.SaveAs
End Sub

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim CustomerName As String
    Dim serviceInvoice As Workbook
    Worksheets("Active").Select
    Customer = ActiveCell
    Set serviceInvoice = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Service Dept\Templates\Service Invoice.xls")
    Worksheets("Invoice1").Select
    Worksheets("Invoice1").Range("B3") = Customer
    serviceInvoice.SaveAs
End Sub

Comment: Awesome..It can now open the invoice on the click. but I'm not sending any data over. Seen like it's sending an empty cell. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: This script assumes that you are positioned on the Cell with the customer name on it. is the command button on the same page? ... if it is  then remove the "Worksheets("Active").Select" line

Comment: Yes the button is located on the active customer sheet. I removed it. I still open the location but the copy and paste part is not working. I this is what I have so far. Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 
Dim CustomerName As String
Dim serviceinvoice As Workbook
 
Set serviceinvoice = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Service Dept\Templates\service invoice")
Worksheets("Invoice1").Select Worksheets("Invoice1").Range("B3")
 
 End Sub

Comment: Thanks for you help Mike I found the next part of the puzzle. I added range("customers").end(xldown).copy and then activesheet.paste before end sub.